# How to typeset boldface ell?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I know that `\ell` gives me this nice mathematical  "calligraphic" letter l, which I want to use throughout my document. However, it is also a common typographic convention that vectors are typeset in boldface as opposed to having a little arrow on top of them.

Hence: How do I get a boldface `\ell`? Simply enclosing it in `\mathbf` does not work...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `\boldsymbol` from the `amsbsy` package; if you are going to use the symbol very often, then you can define a new command, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy}

\newcommand*\Bell{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol\ell}}

\begin{document}

\Bell

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two remarks: `\ensuremath` serves no purpose here; and `bm` is recommended over `amsbsy`; it provides `\boldsymbol` as an alias to `\bm` (it should be loaded *after* `amsmath`).

Answer (score 7):

I could only get it to work using:

```
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand*\boldell{\pmb{\ell}}
```

Comment: `\pmb` is not needed: `\bm{\ell}` does the job.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\ell$\boldmath$\ell$\unboldmath

\end{document}
```

[image]